# How to print a nested dictionary member value in docker volume ls --format

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I want to print the backend volume name of a docker volume using 
docker volume ls --format ,

following is the output of docker volume inspect

```
docker volume inspect 3812bd5a8e286eb9ff9
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "Driver": "oie",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "",
        "Name": "3812bd5a8e286eb9ff9",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "global",
        "Status": {
            "volume_detail": {
                "oie_vol_name": "dcv-TL0SoIuHQvCStS1F-B5i-A",
                "backend": "4000",
                "compression": null,
                "cpg": "cpg1",
                "domain": null,
                "flash_cache": null,
                "fsMode": null,
                "fsOwner": null,
                "mountConflictDelay": 30,
                "provisioning": "thin",
                "size": 20,
                "snap_cpg": "cpg1"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I am able to pull up driver name using docker volume `ls -f driver=hpe --format "{{.Driver}}"`

oie

But when i want to pull field oie_vol_name which is inside `"Status": { "volume_detail":  using " docker volume ls -f driver=hpe --format "{{.Status{.volume_detail{.oie_vol_name}}}}""`

It shows

> Template parsing error: template: :1: unexpected bad character U+007B '{' in command

Comment: Can you try this `docker volume ls -f "{{ .Status.volume_detail.oie_vol_name }}"`

Comment: docker volume ls --format  "{{ .Status.volume_detail.oie_vol_name }}" says "Template parsing error: template: :1:10: executing "" at <.Status.volume_detai...>: can't evaluate field Status in type *formatter.volumeContext"

Comment: the `docker volume inspect` output you provided in the question. Is it complete output?

Comment: Yes it is the complete output

Comment: Sorry my mistake the command should be `docker volume inspect -f "{{ .Status.volume_detail.oie_vol_name }} 3812bd5a8e286eb9ff9`

Comment: Let me put it as answer. So everyone knows.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
docker volume inspect -f "{{ .Status.volume_detail.oie_vol_name }} 3812bd5a8e286eb9ff9
```

Hope this helps.